# javascript not reading value of input -Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Tags: javascript

been trying a while and for some reason not able to get the value of each input

the error im getting is app.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null
    at getProtein (app.js:9)
    at app.js:26

my html

```
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-2">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Age">Age</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control age" id="age" value="25">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="height">Height</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="height" placeholder="Inches" value="167">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="weight">Weight</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="weight" placeholder="lbs" value="255">
          </div>
          <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary active">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="male"  >Male
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
              <input type="radio" name="options" id="female">Female
            </label>
          </div>
        </form>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle"
          type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown"
          aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Activity Level
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Basic Metabolic Rate</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Sedentry</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Lightly Active (Exercise 1-3 Times a Week)</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Moderatly Active (Exercise 3-5 Times a Week)</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Very Active (Exercise 6-7 Times a Week) </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#!">Extra Active (Very Hard Exercise/Physical Job) </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg"type="button" name="calculate" onclick="getProtein()" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
  </div>
  </div>
     <span id="totalProtein"> 0 </span> 


my script 


function getProtein() {

  const age = document.getElementById('age').value;
  const height = document.getElementById('height').value;
  const weight = document.getElementById('weight').value;

  let result = 0;

  if(document.getElementById('male').checked) {
    return result = 66.47 +  (13.75 * weight) + (5.0 * height - (6.75 * age));
  }else if (document.getElementById('female')) {
    return result = 66.47 +  (13.75 * weight) + (5.0 * height - (6.75 * age));
  }

  document.getElementById('totalProtein').innerHTML = Math.round( result );

}


document.getElementById('calculate').onClick = getProtein();
```

it seems to have a problem with the .value, .checked and .innterHTML.

can anyone shine some light on this?

Comment: After return, the rest of your code in function will not be reached...

Comment: Also, male and female calculations are the same? https://jsfiddle.net/6bkopk9j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might call the `getProtein` function too early, so your input-field are not yet ready to be queried, with this line:

```
document.getElementById('calculate').onClick = getProtein();
```

You can rewrite this line:

```
document.getElementById('calculate').onClick = getProtein;
```

or remove it because you already assigned the `getProtein` function to your `calculate` element:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg"type="button" name="calculate" onclick="getProtein()" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
```

Hope this helps.